# wildfly : how to call an EJB from a http servlet

Tags: jboss, ejb, wildfly, war, ear

In wildfly (version 23) I get errors trying to call an EJB 3.0 bean, declared with @Stateless annotation inside a tserver.jar :

at first even lookup would fail :
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: EJBCLIENT000079: Unable to discover destination for request for EJB StatelessEJBLocator for "TServerXmlRpc/tserver/MFProLoginBean", view is interface it.company.tserver.beans.mfpro.login.MFProLogin, affinity is None

now I am getting :
**org.jboss.ejb.client.RequestSendFailedException: EJBCLIENT000409: No more destinations are available**

I can debug the http servlet which is called correctly, I put it both as a .war and an .ear, I can lookup that bean from a standalone java program, to call it I need the server side code which I haven't tried yet.
I can call a similar bean from other jboss tests in an application I'm trying to migrate from jboss 4.2.3.

What could be the matter, any suggestions what to look into ?

this is client invocation that works from a remote java client :

```
package client;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import ejb3.CallerRemote;
public class Client {
     public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception {
          Context context=null;
          try {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
                //props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");// test
                //props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
                
                context = new InitialContext(props);    
                System.out.println("\n\tGot initial Context: "+context);        
          } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
          }

          Object test=context.lookup("ejb:TServerXmlRpc/MFProLoginBean!it.company.tserver.beans.mfpro.login.MFProLogin");
          //   When the invocation starts you try stopping the WildFly and then restart it back to find out if client reconnection works or not.
          CallerRemote remote=(CallerRemote)context.lookup("ejb:TestEAR/remoteEjbOne/CallerBean!ejb3.CallerRemote");
          for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i++) {  
             try {
                   System.out.println("\n\t remote.testMethod(\"MiddlewareMagic!!!\") = "+remote.testMethod("MiddlewareMagic!!!"));
                   Thread.sleep(500);
              } catch(Exception e) {                    
                    System.out.println("\n\tEXCEPTION: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    try{ Thread.sleep(500); } catch(InterruptedException ee) {  ee.printStackTrace(); } 
              }  
          }  
     }
  }
```

with jboss-ejb-client.properties in the classpath of the remote java client, should I place it also inside the war/ear in order to invoke the bean from server side ?

**It seems to me that if I remove the jboss-ejb-client.properties from the classpath of the java client, I get that "no more destinations" errors ...**

I read this :

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB%20invocations%20from%20a%20remote%20server%20instance.html

"If your application is deployed as a top level .war deployment, then the jboss-ejb-client.xml is expected to be placed in .war/WEB-INF/ folder (i.e. the same location where you place any web.xml file)."

where should I put it in a war or ear (as if say the http servlet is acting as "client" towards the same jboss on localhost 127.0.0.1)

this is the structure of the war :

```
META-INF\MANIFEST.MF

WEB-INF\web.xml
WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml

WEB-INF\lib
WEB-INF\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar
WEB-INF\lib\commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
WEB-INF\lib\commons-httpclient-2.0.2.jar
WEB-INF\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar
WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.2.4.jar
WEB-INF\lib\LogManager.jar
WEB-INF\lib\tserver.jar
WEB-INF\lib\compass-core.jar
WEB-INF\lib\xmlrpc-common-3.1.3.jar
WEB-INF\lib\xmlrpc-server-3.1.3.jar

WEB-INF\classes ...

MFDJAds.jsp
MFDJAdsUpload.jsp
MFDJAdsUploaded.jsp
cal.gif
next.gif
prev.gif
ts_picker.js
```

I tried to put the war in a ear too :

```
META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
META-INF\application.xml
META-INF\jboss-ejb-client.properties

TServerXmlRpc.war
tserver.jar

lib\LogManager.jar
lib\compass-core.jar
lib\xmlrpc-common-3.1.3.jar
lib\xmlrpc-server-3.1.3.jar
```

Also what could this wildfly 404 error in undertow be due to :

2021-04-21 06:33:53,910 DEBUG [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-1) Matched default handler path /unified-invoker/JNDIFactory/ejb/v1/invoke/-/JBossTest-server/-/EJB3TestBean/-/it.company.tserver.beans.ejbtest.EJB3Test/test/int/java.util.Date
2021-04-21 06:33:53,916 DEBUG [io.undertow.predicate] (default task-1) Response code set to [404] for HttpServerExchange{ POST /unified-invoker/JNDIFactory/ejb/v1/invoke/-/JBossTest-server/-/EJB3TestBean/-/it.onetech.tserver.beans.ejbtest.EJB3Test/test/int/java.util.Date}.

is it possible to disable EJB authentication for java.lang.SecurityException: WFHTTP000008: Authentication failed

**update :**
it seems to work with this context :

props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

**props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote+http://172.21.93.102:8080");**

both with ejb: path and also this suggestion seems to work :

Notice that the http-remoting client assumes JNDI names in remote lookups are relative to java:jboss/exported namespace, a lookup of an absolute JNDI name will fail.

i.e. to lookup the path after java:jboss/exported in server.log

I suspect there is some quirk in calling an EJB in a war ?

the "exported" is only for beans declared "@remote" ?
how to call a bean declared "@local" ?

with **props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote+http://localhost:8080");**

on jboss server side

**update :**

I have a pattern where beans (in a legacy app) have both a local and remote interface, as described here :

https://living-sun.com/it/java-ee/345617-ejb-remote-local-and-localbean-it39s-correct-to-expose-all-of-them-java-ee-interface-ejb.html

so I found this example for local beans :

http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=822

where I see they don't use @Local annotation but @Remote (?) so I converted the local to remote interface, it shows up in the ejb:methodLocal namespace and seems callable from within jboss with jdni, if anyone has any clue ?

```
2021-04-24 23:31:38,016 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'DataUpdateCheckerBean' in deployment unit 'deployment "TServerXmlRpc.war"' are as follows:

    java:global/TServerXmlRpc/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateCheckerLocal
    java:app/TServerXmlRpc/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateCheckerLocal
    java:module/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateCheckerLocal
    java:jboss/exported/TServerXmlRpc/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateCheckerLocal
    **ejb:/TServerXmlRpc/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateCheckerLocal**
    java:global/TServerXmlRpc/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateChecker
    java:app/TServerXmlRpc/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateChecker
    java:module/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateChecker
    java:jboss/exported/TServerXmlRpc/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateChecker
    ejb:/TServerXmlRpc/DataUpdateCheckerBean!it.company.tserver.beans.dataupdate.DataUpdateChecker
```

Comment: I updated the body of the question, it seems like a joke but honestly I'm trying to possibly migrate an existing jboss 4.2.3 war application to wildfly, in case any possible clues

Comment: I quoted an example that shows how to lookup and call a local bean with @EJB proxy, instead of jndi context lookup and call

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: I am not an expert, but with wildfly 23 I think I had to resort to declaring only "remote" interface, i.e. it won't accept "local" ...